# Why does beautiful soup not properly parse element named "area"?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a python script that uses `beautiful soup` to parse xml documents. Some of the documents contain elements named "area". For some reason I cannot for the life of me properly parse these elements. They always come out as empty `<area/>` elements.

Here is a minimal example of what is happening:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = """""
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' standalone = 'yes'?>

<root>
    <areax>
        foo
    </areax>
    <area>
        bar
    </area>
</root>
"""""
soup = BeautifulSoup (xml, "lxml")

print ("\n#### soup ####\n")
print (soup)

print ("\n#### areax ####\n")
areaxs = soup.find_all ("areax")
for areax in areaxs:
    print (areax)

print ("\n### area ###\n")
areas = soup.find_all ("area")
for area in areas:
    print (area)
```

Output:

```
#### soup ####

<html><body><p>""
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' standalone = 'yes'?>
<root>
<areax>
        foo
    </areax>
<area/>
        bar

</root>
</p></body></html>

#### areax ####

<areax>
        foo
    </areax>

### area ###

<area/>
```

Is the element name "area" protected in any way or is there something else wrong with how I'm parsing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document is parsed as HTML, and the [`area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) element is an empty HTML element (cannot have any children).

To parse it as XML instead, use `BeautifulSoup(xml, "xml")` ([docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id16)):

> By default, Beautiful Soup parses documents as HTML. To parse a document as XML, pass in “xml” as the second argument to the BeautifulSoup constructor:
>
> ```
> soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "xml")
> ```
>
> You’ll need to have lxml installed.

---

The other problem is that you have too many quotes surrounding your `xml` string, so it actually starts with `""` (try printing it). Exactly three quotes (`"""`) should suffice.